# Cant resolve org.jsoup.Jsoup after adding jsoup.jar in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, jsoup

I tried my best to make jsoup working but no luck

i am using Eclipse development tool for android

I created new project and went to build path > Configure build path
in Java build path --- Libraries section, added the external jar

But when I use 
    import org.jsoup.*

eclipse is showing error org.jsoup cant be resolved

I am a passionate coder and this is losing my happiness for last 2 days

Please help

Answer (score 0):

> I created new project and went to build path > Configure build path in Java build path --- Libraries section, added the external jar

That is not how to add JARs in Android. Undo that, then copy the JAR into your project's `libs/` directory. That will automatically add it to both your build path *and* the app itself, so it is available at runtime.